# Creating custom unique Id for new record but having duplicate error

Tags: python, django-models

creating an id and trying to insert a record with it, but having duplication error.

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "1062 (23000): Duplicate entry
> '715683160' for key 'projects_project.PRIMARY'", '23000')

```
import random


def makeUniqueLongId():
  return random.randint(100000000, 999999999)


class Project(models.Model):
  id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True, default=makeUniqueLongId(), editable=False)
  ...
```

How can I prevent id duplication? Is `unique=True` not enough to return new id with `makeUniqueLongId()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not create a unique ID, but just a random one. The more often you run makeUniqueLongId() the higher is the probability that you will eventually get a duplicate ID.

Django's unique=True will prevent that an entry will be saved if its value already exists and that's exactly why you're getting the error (see documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#unique)). Moreover, since you are setting primary_key = True, there is no need for unique, because that condition will be set automatically.

Try adding a custom save() method to your model:

```
def makeUniqueLongId():
  return random.randint(100000000, 999999999)

class Project(models.Model):
  id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
  ...

# while id is not yet set, create new random id. If random id not already exists, save as new id.

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while not self.id:
            new_id = makeUniqueLongId()
        if not type(self).objects.filter(id=new_id).exists():
            self.id = new_id
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I implemented `save()` method under the `Project` model but error says: `AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Project instances`

Comment: @yvl Right, please check if it works when you use type(self).objects, because the manager cannot be accessed from a model instance. Type(self) will return the model itself. Updated the answer.